# Show, using only the definition, that if $\{X_n\}$ is Cauchy and $C\in\mathbb{R}$ then $\{CX_n\}$ is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let me know if what I did this correct please.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, we want to find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|CX_n-CX_m |<\epsilon$  $\forall n,m\geq N$.
$$|CX_n-CX_m |=|C||X_n-X_m |$$
$∃N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|X_n-X_m |<\epsilon/|C|$       $\forall n,m\geq N$
Hence $CX_n$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Basically fine. The trivial case $C=0$ should either be dealt with separately, or we can use $\frac{\epsilon}{|C|+1}$ to avoid dividing by $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: This sounds like an answer as the question is: "Is this OK?" and your answer is "Yes, it is, basically."

Comment: Someone may want to suggest stylistic improvements. I haveonly commented on a piece of (technical) incorrectness.

Comment: How about the |C|=0 part? Can I just say it's true for |C|does not equal to zero?

Comment: What do you mean by stylistic improvements?